# PowerShell ISE doesn't flush stdout

Tags: command-line, powershell, powershell-ise

I'm having a little problem when running a console program in PowerShell ISE: when the program writes out a line in portions using flush, PowerShell won't show the line until the program writes a line ending. For example the program is doing something like this (C++):

```
std::cout << "Doing something time-consuming..." << std::flush;
// Do something for some time
std::cout << " done in " << x << " seconds" << std::endl;
```

And PowerShell ISE will only show the whole line when this section of code completes. With non-ISE PowerShell this doesn't happen, the line is printed in portions as expected.
So the question is: can I somehow make PowerShell ISE disable its internal buffer and print the program's stdout directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is not possible, at least without hacking it through Reflection (as I [was told](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f783a112-e822-4824-ba03-73c54799745e/powershell-ise-doesnt-flush-stdout) at the Microsoft forum).
I think I just should use another tool as an advanced alternative to cmd, like [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) or [ConEmu](http://www.fosshub.com/ConEmu.html) (which can also run a PowerShell console inside its interface).